# Dart null safety !. vs ?-

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

what is the difference exactly between

```
String id = folderInfo!.first.id;   //this works
```

and

```
String id = folderInfo?.first.id; //this is an error
```

I know ?. returns null when the value object is null but what does the !. return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`?.`** is known as **[Conditional member access](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#other-operators)**

> the leftmost operand can be null; example: foo?.bar selects property bar from expression foo unless foo is null (in which case the value of foo?.bar is null)

In your case, `String id` means `id` can not have `null` value. But using `?.` can return `null` that's why it is showing errors.

**`!.`** is use **If you know that an expression never evaluates to `null`.**

For example, a variable of type int? Might be an integer, or it might be null. If you know that an expression never evaluates to null but Dart disagrees, you can add `!` to assert that it isn’t null (and to throw an exception if it is).

More and ref:
[important-concepts of null-safety](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts) and [operators.](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#other-operators)

Answer (score 3):

**The Assertion Operator (!)**

Use the null `assertion` operator **( ! )** to make **Dart** treat a `nullable` expression as non-nullable if you’re certain it isn’t `null`.

In other words **!.** will throw an `error` if the `value` is null and will break your function and as you know **?.** will return null with no interruption.

Answer (score 0):

The `!` throws an error if the variable is `null`. You should try to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re sure that an expression with a nullable type isn’t null, you can use a null assertion operator (!) to make Dart treat it as non-nullable. By adding ! just after the expression, you tell Dart that the value won’t be null, and that it’s safe to assign it to a non-nullable variable.

In your first case, you define id not nullable but when you set nullable value then throw error.

```
String id = folderInfo?.first.id;
```

In 2nd case, when you use assertion operator (!), it actually tell compiler that it must be non nullable.